# mysql syntax not selecting multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return the `country_language_id` column. When I specify the a single `country_id`, then it works, but when I try to select on multiple `country_id`s, the result is still 1.

```
SELECT country_language_id FROM country_master where row_active=1 and country_id=2;
```

result=1

```
SELECT country_language_id FROM country_master where row_active=1 and country_id=3;
```

result=4

```
SELECT country_language_id FROM country_master where row_active=1 and country_id=2 and 3;
```

result=1

Comment: `...and (country_id=2 or country_id=3);`

Comment: Or `...... AND (country_id IN(2, 3)`  should give the same results